# Matrix-like boxplots for dataframe with 3-level multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with a 3-level multiindex like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    B=[3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
    C=[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    D=list(range(12)),
))
df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C'], inplace=True)
```

Now for each index tuple of the first two levels (`A` and `B`) I would like to create a boxplot over the third index level (`C`) and arrange the resulting subplots in a matrix where rows represent the first index level (`A`) and columns the second index level (`B`).

[`DataFrameGroupBy.boxplot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.boxplot.html) looks promising, so I gave it a try:

```
df.groupby(level=['A', 'B']).boxplot(column='D', layout=(2, 2))
```

however I get the following error: `KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]"`.

Since [`DataFrame.boxplot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) also supports a group `by` parameter, I also tried this:

```
df.reset_index().boxplot(by=['A', 'B'], column='D', layout=(2, 2))
```

That kind of works, however it ignores the `layout` specification and just puts everything in one subplot (even though it seems to create 4 subplots):

[image: Boxplot]

In the end I would like to obtain something like the following:

```
import itertools as it
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

for (index, group), ax in zip(df.groupby(level=['A', 'B']), it.chain.from_iterable(axes)):
    ax.boxplot(group['D'])
    ax.set_xticklabels([str(index)])

plt.show()
```

[image: Boxplot expected]

Is this possible with one of Pandas `boxplot` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of how to do this with `DataFrame.boxplot`, but just in case you're open to seaborn, you can do this with [**`seaborn.catplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html):

```py
sns.catplot(y='D', row='A', col='B', width=0.1, kind='box', data=df.reset_index())
```

[image: catplot with multiindex]

Or with `sharey=False`:

[image: catplot with multiindex and sharey=False]